# Rails (now) not liking my jquery script which turned <td> elements into links. "undefined method" error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, html-table

Here is the erring portion of the view (show.html.erb)

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<tr class="tweets">

    <script>
        $("td.status").click(function(){
        window.location = "http://www.twitter.com/id/status/<%= r.page_id %>";
        });
    </script>
    <td class="user"><img src="<%= r.img_url %>"></td>

    <td class="user"><strong><%= r.screen_name %></strong></td>

    <td class="user"><%= r.real_name %></td>

    <td class="time"><%= r.time_ago %></td>
    <td class="status"><%= r.status %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Note that when I remove the jquery script all other r.element tags work. The @results object instantiated in this view's controller (called here) calls this script (I'm only showing part of it)

```
module SimpleTwitter
  class Tweet

attr_accessor :img_url, :screen_name, :real_name, :status, :time_ago

def initialize(tweet_hash)
  @img_url = tweet_hash['profile_image_url']
  @screen_name = tweet_hash['from_user']
  @real_name = tweet_hash['from_user_name']
  @status = tweet_hash['text']
  @page_id = tweet_hash['id']
  ...(cont)...
```

There is a lot of complicated (to me anyway) parsing going on here through a series of files, gems, classes, but know that without the jquery script which "linkifies" given  elements, all is working well. Previously I used this jquery script without error.

Please let me know if you'd like more information.

EDIT (DOH!) --- here's the error message:

```
NoMethodError in Searches#show

Showing /home/ddouglas/Develop/twitter_research/app/views/searches/show.html.erb where     line #28 raised:

undefined method `page_id' for #<SimpleTwitter::Tweet:0x000000030ee590>
Extracted source (around line #28):

25: 
26:         <script>
27:             $("td.status").click(function(){
28:             window.location = "http://www.twitter.com/id/status/<%=         r.page_id %>";
29:             });
30:         </script>
31:         <td class="user"><img src="<%= r.img_url %>"></td>
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the jquery script other than the fact that the script tries to use r.page_id which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: SimpleTwitter is a gem which queries twitter using the HTTParty gem. Its an exercise in OO design, hiding implementation logic, etc.

Comment: `window.location = "http://www.twitter.com/id/status/"+<%= r.page_id %>;` ?

Comment: Cheung prompted a search. I've updated the source code to show where I went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attr_accessor for the Tweet class did not include :page_id

Thanks cheung